# Android: Why Am I Failing To Login in Android Application?

Tags: php, android

I don't know the reason why am I failing to log in from the android application.

I am making an application where the user needs to log in from the android login form. But when i click on the login button, i get the error which is given below.

```
04-13 15:16:24.159: E/linker(12897): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
04-13 15:16:40.406: E/log_tag(12897): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
```

Following is the java source code (Investor.java):

```
package com.example.entrepreneurexpress;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Investors extends Activity {

    StringBuffer buffer;
    InputStream inputStream;
    String result = null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.investors_index);
        ActionBar aBar = getActionBar();
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemailAddress);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (email.length() >= 1) {
                    email.setText("");
                }
                if (password.length() >= 1) {
                    password.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAdd = email.getText().toString();
                String pasWord = password.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("emailAdd", emailAdd);
                editor.putString("password", pasWord);
                editor.commit();

                try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://116.73.36.17/AdroidApp/select.php");

                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserEmail", emailAdd));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pasWord));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

                try{
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     String line = null;
                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");                                
                     }
                     inputStream.close();
                     result=sb.toString();
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                 }
                try {
                     JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                     CharSequence w = (CharSequence) json_data.get("re");
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
            }
        });

        Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.investorRegister);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent invRegister = new Intent(Investors.this,
                        InvestorRegister.class);
                startActivity(invRegister);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the source code that I am using to check in php..

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "EntrepreneurExpress");

    if (!$con) {
        die('Connection Aborted ! <br />' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $email = $_POST['emailAdd'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Brokers WHERE EmailID = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Some Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $r["re"] = "Welcome !";
        print(json_encode($r));
        echo "Y";
    } else {
        $r["re"] = "Bye ! " .mysqli_error($con);
        print(json_encode($r));
        echo "<br />N";
    }

?>
```

Where am I making the mistake ? Kindly guide me.

Comment: Give more lines of the stack trace.

Comment: that's the only error given in the stacktrace..

Comment: `NetWorkOnMainThreadException`?? running n/w operation on ui thread

Comment: Beware, when you catch an exception, the following try block should not be executed. Either you nest them, but it would be hard to read, or you simply return from the method, or you throw some exception.

Comment: so what am i suppose to do ?

Comment: More lines means you just kept the first top line, which is not enough.

Comment: Sir, am getting that line only in the stack trace.

Comment: Oh, that's because you don't propagate the exception. When you log, add a third parameter to invoke the log method, it's the exception itself. If you don't do that, you loose the exception and its stack trace. Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result ", e);

Answer (score 0):

Your   result=sb.toString(); is still   null , ie  your server is not returning any value to your application ,check  by  below   code

Log.d("result", "result string from server:"+result);